# Proof that a certain set of polynomials is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

For $c_0, \ldots, c_n$ pairwise distinct complex numbers. Show that the polynomials $((X-c_i)^n)_{0 \leq i \leq n}$ are linearly independent.

I need to prove it without induction.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? When you write down a linear combination of these polynomials and assume it is zero, what conclusions can you draw?

Comment: I tried this method, it's not obvious to me to see all the scalars are 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the Binomial theorem, $$\sum_{k=0}^n p_k(x-c_k)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n p_k\sum_{j=0}^n\binom njc_k^jx^{n-j}=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom nj\sum_{k=0}^n p_kc_k^j\,x^{n-j}.$$

Identifying to the zero polynomial,

$$\sum_{k=0}^n p_kc_k^j=0.$$

This is a Vandermonde system, which only has the trivial solution (the determinant is nonzero).

Comment: It seems that the polynomials must all have degree $n$,

Comment: @Wuestenfux: ooops, yes.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement that the numbers are pairwise distinct is redundant as all polynomials have a different degree and thus must be linearly independent. Note that any scalar of a polynomial

Comment: $(x-1)^n$ and $(x-1)^n$ are not linearly independent. The condition is needed

Comment: All polynomials have the same degree.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to write a linear combination of your starting expressions $(x-c_i)^n$ as a single polynomial, then equal each of the coefficients of the "monster polynomial" to zero. Since:

$$(x-c_i)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} x^k c_i^{n-k}$$

Let there be a linear combination of those $(x-c_i)^n$ such that:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \beta_i(x-c_i)^n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\beta_i\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} x^k c_i^{n-k} = 0$$

Then we can put everything into the "inner" sum and flip the order of the two sums:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^k {n \choose k} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \beta_i c_i^{n-k} = 0$$

So, for each $k=0,1,...n$,

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \beta_i c_i^{n-k} = 0 $$

Can you go on from here? Note that $0$ on the first two equations represents the zero-polynomial, while in the last one it's just good old scalar $0$